# Crashlytics error: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

After I updated Fabric Crashlytics in my app I cant anymore run it on my iOS device. On simulator it works fine. Error is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>         "_gzopen", referenced from:
>             -[CLSPackageReportOperation compressFile:] in Crashlytics(CLSPackageReportOperation.o)
>         "_gzwrite", referenced from:
>             ___42-[CLSPackageReportOperation compressFile:]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSPackageReportOperation.o)
>         "_gzclose", referenced from:
>             -[CLSPackageReportOperation compressFile:] in Crashlytics(CLSPackageReportOperation.o)
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Comment: It looks like you need link to `zlib`.

Comment: add `libc++` and you are done.

Comment: I've already answered that question on this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569861/8434514](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569861/8434514)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. I removed Crashlytics.framework and reinstall it.

Answer (score 50):

Crashlytics and Fabric require you to link your target against the following:

- Security.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- libc++
- libz

Just select your target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries -> add the ones missing.

I hope it helped.

Comment: This works. Make sure you also add this to any test targets! That was my problem.

Answer (score 20):

I solved this issue by just adding `$(inherited)` to other linker flags in Build Settings.

Answer (score 16):

I run into a similar issue, when I was updating an app that was created before Xcode 5.

Since Xcode 5 new projects build with modules enabled by default. In my old app "Enable Modules" was set to "No". So this was the solution.

[image: In the Build Settings set Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) to YES]

Answer (score 6):

For me, the solution was Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries add libc++ and works, in my legacy project.

Answer (score 4):

My solution for this problem was:

Change "Build Active Architecture Only" to "Yes" also for "Release".

The setting can be found selecting your project > "Build Settings" > "Targets" (your target) > "Architectures"

[image]

**do it in your project targets and also do it in your projectTest targets**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Extending [Ricardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200183/crashlytics-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64/38098721#38098721) here. Select the “Build Phases” tab, click the “+” next to “Link Binary With Libraries” and add -

1. Security.framework
2. SystemConfiguration.framework
3. StoreKit.framework
4. libsqlite3.tbd
5. libz.tbd
6. libc++.tbd

As per Google, developers should use Crashlytics [via Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started). This worked for me as of Firebase v5.16.0 and Fabric v1.9.0 (Xcode 10.1).

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by adding **$(inherited) $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC -l"sqlite3" -l"z" -l"c++" -framework "Crashlytics" -framework "Fabric" -framework "Security" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -framework "UIKit"** to other linker flags in Build Settings.

Answer (score 1):

On **M1 Mac**

In Excluded Architectures Add "Any iOS Simulator SDK" - "arm64" in Target, Test, and all libraries you added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Project(not target) Info tab set the configuration file to none and run `pod install` again

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing "library which causes the error" from other linker flags.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).