# Can't Build my app after upgrading to Fabric from Crashlytics

Tags: ios, ios9, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

After upgrading my iOS application to Fabric from Crashlytics using Xcode 7 I got following error

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>            "_FABNetworkMaximumRetryCount", referenced from:
>             ___51-[CLSBetaController loadUpdateWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke in  Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
>                -[CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient transmitLogFilesAtURLs:toURL:withAPIKey:completionHandler:] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient.o)
>              ___51-[CLSBetaController loadUpdateWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
>         -[CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient transmitLogFilesAtURLs:toURL:withAPIKey:completionHandler:] in Crashlytics(CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Any advice?

Comment: I've already answered that question on this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569861/8434514](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569861/8434514)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue in the following steps.

1. Remove reference fabric.framework and crashlytics.framework from project
2. Clean the project
3. Remove my application from Device and restart my device.
4. Relaunch Fabric app after once quit from my applications
5. Select required application from application list On Fabric
6. Click to migrate crashlytics then follow the instruction by Fabric

At the end my application build and run successfully on device as well as simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me while trying to sideload GBA4iOS on my device.

A kick fix would be to set an old Crashlytics version in the Podfile after cleaning the project.

For Example:

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics', '3.1.1'
```

Then run on terminal:

```
pod install
```

And open the project again.

Hope it helps until you find a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem but somehow I managed to get it working by adding libz.tbd and libc++.tbd to the list of frameworks.