# Why doesn't following the Fabric.IO steps for Twitter Login work for Android apps?

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

When you go to Fabric.io and login you choose a project type of android the site will guide you to download the plugin.
[image: Fabric.io step one only]
The first (terrible) thing to notice is that the web page will never let you past this horrific graphic which is meaningless.  There is no way to ever get to step 2.  That's because Step 2 says, "Launch your app" but you cannot, because it cannot build because the Fabric.io steps seem to be incomplete.

Here are the graphics detailing each step that Fabric.IO plugin walks you through unsuccessfully.

**Click fabric io plugin button**
[image: click fabric io plugin button (AndroidStudio 1.5)]
[image: click start button]
**click twitter choice**
[image: click fabric twitter choice]
**click login with twitter - get code**
[image: click login with twitter - get code]
**Copy Layout code**
[image: copy layout code]
**add the java code for login**
[image: copy java code to add code for login]
**Last step -- and yet it does not work -WILL NOT BUILD!!!**
[image: Failure]

**Examine First Graphic Again**

Now, look at the first graphic again.  You cannot Launch Your App because **it will not build.**

I cannot find out how to add the library which contains the TwitterLoginButton.
Anyone have any ideas?
I've spent hours on this, searching SO, trying various things.  Quite a waste of time.

You know, I use C# and Nuget and it just works.  This is not a great package system.

**Gradle file**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
            // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
            // quickly to Android tooling updates
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
            classpath'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.3.1@aar'

        }
    }
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Comment: show us your gradle file

Comment: added gradle file to original post

Comment: By the way, the gradle items are _not_ mentioned at all within the "wizard" that runs when you click that Fabric.io plugin button.  I found those settings and added them after the plugin wizard didn't work at all.  This is very poorly documented system -- but not only poorly documented, poorly working.  It's too bad.  It's just a waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@daylight Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here. First off, thanks for the feedback on the layout and code. Second, it looks like the SDK wasn't installed before going through the code samples. If you click "Install" in this screenshot at the top, that will get you the SDK and other code needed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will try it.

Comment: That was the solution.  I tried this on two different computers and just couldn't see that option.  I even thought it had to do with that missing library since it was complaining about TwitterLoginButton but I couldn't see that I missed the Install of the separate plugin for some reason.  I was code-blind, I guess.  Thanks again.

Comment: I understand why I believe I couldn't ever _see_ other option. It's a contextual thing & the way information leads us to think something.  In this case I knew the only thing I wanted to make my app be able to do was Login with Twitter.  This seems to be a mutually exclusive choice from the other one. That guided me move to the bottom choice each time.  Also, there is no text associated with the Twitter 1.11.0 which might've explained that it is a core component that is needed.  Finally, think about all the steps I followed to get here - installing the FabricIO plugin into AndroidStudio etc.

Comment: Glad to hear that did the trick and thanks for the additional feedback and details. I'll share it with the team.

Comment: @MikeBonnell can you please let us know why we get error: "Error:Crashlytics was applied to a project without an Android plugin. Please make sure the Crashlytics plugin is applied after the appropriate Android plugin for your project." when we are using this in the library project

Comment: @Shubham I'd recommend creating a new SO question as that's a different underlying question.