# Crashlytics in iOS failed to proceed "Build and run your app" step

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, crashlytics, xcode10.1

I've added `Firebase Crashlytics` by removing `Firebase crash` as per official documentation provided by the Firebase. Everything done accordingly but `Build and run your app` step failed to detect my app building with no reason. I went through some questions in here like [Crashlytics in iOS won't proceed past “Build Your Project” in Fabric app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117477/crashlytics-in-ios-wont-proceed-past-build-your-project-in-fabric-app) but solutions not worked for me. I've properly set "Debug Information Format" to "DWARF with dSYM File" as well. Why firebase failed to detect "Build and run your app" step for my app?

Comment: Have you added the Crashlytics run script in Build Phases tab & Also recheck whether you have changed Ddebug Information Format to  "DWARF with dSYM File" for both Debug n Release or for any other scheme if you have...

Comment: @SiddharthSunil Yes. Checked & Already done.

Comment: have you checked you info.plist for a "Fabric" key? if there... delete it and try again

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project in firebase console. Find "Download the latest config file" under "Your apps" section. Download the GoogleService-info.plist. 
Now Go to your xcode project. Delete existing GoogleService-info.plist and add the recently downloaded file to your project.

It worked for me.