# No new App created in Fabric though fastlane beta says build uploaded to Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics, fastlane

I've been able to create and upload one new iOS app and two new Android apps in Fabric however, this particular iOS build will not upload to Fabric. I have gone through all the [motions](https://fabric.io/kits/fastlane) outlined in their tutorials and can run `fastlane beta` which runs successfully and says

```
[15:14:12]: Uploading the build to Crashlytics Beta. Time for some ☕️.
[15:14:20]: Build successfully uploaded to Crashlytics Beta 
[15:14:20]: Visit https://fabric.io/_/beta to add release notes and notify testers.
```

However, this doesn't produce an app in Fabric. When I run through the steps for a [Crashlytics upload](https://www.fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics) either using the manual option or using the Mac App, I am unsuccessful. The Fabric app just leaves me with "to continue, build your Xcode project by pressing command-B," which does not do anything, I'm just stuck at that screen. I have tried every answer outlined in the Stack Overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117477/crashlytics-in-ios-wont-proceed-past-build-your-project-in-fabric-app) which should have addressed this problem but does not for me.

In short, I have successfully uploaded two Android apps and an iOS app to Fabric using this workflow but cannot get this iOS app to upload regardless of what's indicated by the command line.

If it matters, this is Cordova app.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was tricky and bizarre so I'll post it for future reference. The trick was two steps (as far as I can tell, this is what made it work). First, run:

`./Crashlytics.framework/submit *api_key* *build_secret* -ipaPath ./buildname.ipa -emails ***@*** -notifications YES`

in the directory which contains your `Crashlytics.framework` file. This is probably the same folder as your `xcodeproj` file for your app. You should have this file in that directory after following the steps outlined in my post above.

Then open the `xcodeproj` and build and run the file (for me I had to run it on an emulator not just the physical iPhone I had connected to my Mac).

This created a new Fabric app. I have not seen any answers like this on Stack Overflow so hopefully this is helps anyone like me. I still have no idea what the root issue really was here.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing the answer here! :)