# Fabric issue App not showing after following instruction

Tags: react-native, google-fabric, fabric.io

I have carefully followed the instruction from fabric (https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install) to install crashlytics in my app. However I cannot select my app after the instruction since my app is not showing. I have tried most of the solution that has been given in this question here ([Crashlytics in iOS won't proceed past "Build Your Project" in Fabric app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117477/crashlytics-in-ios-wont-proceed-past-build-your-project-in-fabric-app))

But I still failed to get my app in fabric.
I am using react native to develop my app and using Xcode Version 10.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Fabric/Firebaser here - If you've gone through all the necessary instructions, try cleaning your project first before building and running again to try to get your app up on your dashboard. And if you haven't seen it, here are some instructions specifically for setting up react native apps with Crashlytics: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fabric#crashlytics-usage). And make sure that if you haven't, set the Debug Information Format to DWARF with dSYM file for both debug and release as specified in that SO post you linked.

You can also see more debug information about Fabric if you set Fabric to debug mode in your initialization statement: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html. Check to see if the settings requests are being made to Fabric or if there is anything unusual.

If you're still having trouble, reach out to support(at)fabric(dot)io with your app's bundle ID and support will be able to help you out more.